# How to use Shape Distance and Common Interfaces to find Hausdorff Distance in Opencv?

Tags: opencv

I would like to find Hausdorff Distance between two Canny detector output image which contains group of contours, to find the similarity of two Shapes. For that i need to Find Hausdorff Distance Estimation. Does Opencv has this function implemented in it?
I've found [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/shape/doc/shape_distances.html) in Opencv API Reference but i cant find How to use it anywhere.
Could anyone please guide me how to use this functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's a [nice sample on github](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/shape_example.cpp)
for this, but you 'll need opencv3.0 (master branch) to use it.

actually , the hausdorff distance itself is not that big mystery,

```
// internal helper:
int distance_2( const std::vector<cv::Point> & a, const std::vector<cv::Point>  & b )
{
    int maxDistAB = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {
        int minB = 1000000;
        for (size_t j=0; j<b.size(); j++)
        {
            int dx = (a[i].x - b[j].x);     
            int dy = (a[i].y - b[j].y);     
            int tmpDist = dx*dx + dy*dy;

            if (tmpDist < minB)
            {
                minB = tmpDist;
            }
            if ( tmpDist == 0 )
            {
                break; // can't get better than equal.
            }
        }
        maxDistAB += minB;
    }
    return maxDistAB;
}

double distance_hausdorff( const std::vector<cv::Point> & a, const std::vector<cv::Point> & b )
{
    int maxDistAB = distance_2( a, b );
    int maxDistBA = distance_2( b, a );   
    int maxDist = std::max(maxDistAB,maxDistBA);

    return std::sqrt((double)maxDist);
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this; `maxDistAB += minB`? Arean't you supposed to compute the minimum distances instead? According to [this](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/98/normand/main.html), that is what you're supposed to do